Bottle's app how to access local file
Using Linux Mint Mate 21.3 and Bottles version 51.11,
I've successfully installed PDF-XChange.
Now, I need to open a PDF located outside of Bottles directories.
What's the method to do so?
Also, I'm wondering if there's a way to create a desktop shortcut to quickly launch PDF-XChange.

following upstream, all you need to do is flatpak override --user --filesystem="path" com.usebottles.bottles
then open your favorite text editor and add the following:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=PDF-XChange
Exec=wine "/path/to/PDF-XChange.exe/"
Icon=/path/to/iconfile
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;

chmod +x the .desktop file or right click on it and mark it as executable
then you can always open it from that .desktop file
